# want to make the service independently run

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service

So basically what i am trying to do is i want a service that runs in background and updates the LatLong to the server. This operation needs to happen all the time even if the application is running or not.
Now when the application is launched i want the service to calculate the distance between the latlong and update the UI in addition to the work that it was already doing i.e. updating the latlong to the server. i want the service to do the additional work for multiple activities. lets say i launch the application and i am on Activity A, onclick of a button on Activity A the service starts updating the UI and when we click gain it stops updating. Now i am on Activity B and on click  i want the service to do some work in addition to the updation of LatLong and update the UI. 
What would be the best approach to achieve this.??

**EDIT**
The problem i am facing is not getting the service update the  UI but making the activity communicate with the service when it has already started. 
i can pass on some data when i am starting the service but how to communicate with the service when it has already started. How to tell the service that see you are already running and doing some operations now you have to perform some  more operation on top of the previous operation.

I can make some static method in the service and call them when i need to perform the extra operation but i dont wanna do that.. i want to better approach.

Comment: You have to use IntentService. Take a look at the below example. http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android

Comment: @Nilanchala please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basically services runs on the same main thread process as ui. When you want make it run continuously you have run it in your tread. In this way you avoid service being get stopped as application go in background or killed. (Please take look at Service.START_STICKY flag, this is what you need as i guess).

And more coming your second problem of activity getting updated with service information or data that is being collected for this you need look at " How Bind the service". (In activity check for service connection and Binding to a activity, Unbindibg is also there have look at it also). Activity has all the call backs for it you need to implement binder.

**EDIT**

Service to update ui has to have send and receive intent mechanism. You can broadcast and intent from the services check your activity is running or not. If running broadcast intent and have receiver in activity to listen it.

You can do it by interface mechanism too

Comment: Have a look at my edited question. can you shed some more light on it.

Comment: The service can send message to activity via intend and the activity can listen to it through BroadcastIntent. But how can i send messages to the service from activity when it is already running? Like if i want to call method that changes some value in the service when its already running. how can i achieve that.?

Comment: From Binder class you can do it. Have method which returns running service and call that method(public access specifier). Binder will be given to during the service connection

Comment: okey lemme try that. and if you can update your answer with some code then it will be helpful.